# Hightlight entire row if two columns match and are not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I looked and although there is likely something here, I'm too new to VBA to make it work.

I want to sort a range of data, and highlight a row if two particular columns match, as long as one column (K) is not blank.

More Details:
If column D = column K and column K is not blank, then highlight that row.
The amount of rows will change depending on the day.
The dataset starts at row 3.

I was thinking to use `.end(xlup)` to copy the formula.

This can be accomplished through conditional formatting, but I'm trying to build this in VBA so that it will be a one button solution.

Comment: Thanks!  It was only highlighting starting at Column D, but I modified it to get the whole row.  Now, I just have to do some research to learn more about Dim and "C as range"  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version you can look at

```
Sub DoIt()

    Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

    Set Rng = Columns("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Columns("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
    For Each C In Rng.Cells

        If C.Offset(, -7) = C Then

            Range(Cells(C.Row, "K"), Cells(C.Row, "D")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else: Range(Cells(C.Row, "K"), Cells(C.Row, "D")).Interior.Color = xlNone

        End If

    Next C
End Sub
```